# Swap Azure Webapp slot to production slot with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have an Azure appservice with 3 deployment slots for which I want to swap the slots with powershell using the Azure powershell module. I have the following slots :

- production ( the original appservice )
- staging
- test
  [image: DeploymentSlots]

I use the following command:

```
Switch-AzWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName $SOURCE_SLOT -DestinationSlotName $TARGET_SLOT -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP -Name $APP_NAME
```

Using the test and staging slots at the source and destination parameters works perfectly, but how can I swap for example the staging slot with the production slot?

Using production as destination slot will result in a resource not found exception.

The Switch-AzWebAppSlot -name does not work because I have more than 2 deployment slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your script, using `-DestinationSlotName "production"` works just fine.

Comment: Indeed "production" worked. Not sure where the typo was but If you want to target the production slot "production" works. Thankyou,